# Populate Select Tag with Nested JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a nested JSON Object that I am trying to traverse in order to populate options in a `<select>` tag, based on which select option a user chooses

First Select Tag:

```
<select name="food-category" id="food-category">
    <option id="italian">Italian</option>
    <option id="bbq">BBQ</option>
</select>
```

JSON response returned on select `change` event

```
{
    "food-types": {
        "italian": [
            {"pasta": "Pasta"},
            {"pizza": "Pizza"},
            {"chicken-parm": "Chick Paremesan"},
        ],
        "bbq": [
            {"ribs": "Ribs"},
            {"burger": "Burger"},
            {"steak": "Steak"}
        ]
    }
}
```

I have an Ajax request that populates my `<options>`, however with every single object inside of a distinct food type category.

```
$('#food-category').on('change', function (e) {
//AJAX request omitted for brevity
var data = this.get('responseData');
foodTypes= data.["food-types"];

for(key in foodTypes) {
    if(foodTypes.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    $('#search-food').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + foodTypes[key] + '</option>');
}
```

So in my Second Select Tag, a single option ends up being

```
<select name="search-food" id="search-food">
    <option value="food-type">[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]</option> 
</select>
```

How can I get my options to display only single food type category per option from the nested JSON response? I was thinking a function that checks the value of the food-category and returns the category selected using a case statement, but I'm not sure how I'd plug that into my for-loop that sets the key-values.

Hope this all makes sense - can include more details if needed

Comment: that is a really poor data structure. Would be a lot simpler using something like `{value: "pasta", text: "Pasta"}` then you have consistent keys to work with

Comment: If that were the case wouldn't each option be output as `<option value="value">` as set in my for-loop?

Comment: no, you would adjust output to use the known object keys

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to decide what you want to do with your data. `foodTypes[key]` will return an *array* containing objects such as `{"pasta": "Pasta"}`. So yeah, your output sounds about right. Say you have a variable `selectedFoodType` that contains which array to loop through, you could then do.

```
// Say selectedFoodType is a string "italian" that you got from somewhere
var myFoods = foodTypes[selectedFoodType]; 

for(key in myFoods) { // Then myFoods will be your array of pasta, pizza etc
    if(myFoods.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      $('#search-food').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + myFoods[key] + '</option>');
    }
}
```

If you want to loop through ALL the foods, then you need to delve further into the structure with f.e. a second `for` loop

```
for(i in foodTypes) {
    var myFoods = foodTypes[i];
    // From here it's the exact same thing as the example above
    // just now we're fetching the key from the outer for-loop
    // and because of the outer loop we're doing it for each foodType
    for(j in myFoods) {
        if(myFoods.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
          $('#search-food').append('<option value="' + j + '">' + myFoods[j] + '</option>');
        }
    }
}
```